# How to print a java Set of Sets elements in sorted order?

Tags: java, list, set

In my program I have a `HashSet<HashSet<Integer>>`, at then end of my program I'm printing the contents using the following statement,

```
System.out.println("Groups: " + allSets.toString());
```

It shows me this,

```
Groups: [[17], [19], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 14, 15, 16, 18, 20, 21], [11], [13]]
```

My answer is **okay**, but I would like to see it in **sorted** like,

```
Groups: [[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 14, 15, 16, 18, 20, 21], [11], [13], [17], [19]]
```

I'm inserting into the Set all the single numbered sets in sorted order and I have to insert the big set at the end.

I tried with `TreeSet` but it doesn't work, (`got some exceptions`).

I solved my problem using `List` instead of `Set`,

I'm wondering, **is there any way** to get the same ordered output by using `Set`?

Comment: So, to be clear: you want to sort the sets individually, and then sort the sets as a group based on the smallest element of the set?

Comment: The individual sets are sorted, all I need to insert the big set at first position, which I can't in Set. So I solved it using List.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a `TreeSet` for the outer set, you just need to give it a valid comparator.  I would recommend something like

```
SortedSet<SortedSet<Integer>> outerSet = new TreeSet<SortedSet<Integer>>(
  Comparator.comparingInt(SortedSet::first));
```

(assuming Java 8).

Answer (score 1):

```
     HashSet<HashSet<Integer>> allSets = new HashSet<>();
     List<Set<Integer>> out=allSets.stream().
                            sorted((x, y) -> x.iterator().next() - y.iterator().next()).
                            collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: It also works, but one correction, " List<Set<Integer>> out ", otherwise it shows error.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I'm unable to comment on answer. But accepted answer could not accurate.
You should be very careful with comparators when using Tree in java. 
Once your comparator returns 0 it's assumed objects are equal, so will not be added into Tree.

If your sets expected to contain all unique numbers, just ignore this answer!

Otherwice:
Comparator proposed by [Louis Wasserman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/869736/louis-wasserman) compares **by first element only**! So in case 
Try next code to test it:

```
        SortedSet<Integer> s1 = new TreeSet<>(Arrays.asList(13, 14, 15, 16, 17));
        SortedSet<Integer> s2 = new TreeSet<>(Arrays.asList(13, 19));
        SortedSet<Integer> s3 = new TreeSet<>(Arrays.asList(13, 133));
        SortedSet<Integer> s4 = new TreeSet<>(Arrays.asList(110, 13));
        SortedSet<Integer> s5 = new TreeSet<>(Collections.singletonList(13));
        SortedSet<Integer> s6 = new TreeSet<>(Arrays.asList(13,16));
        SortedSet<Integer> s7 = new TreeSet<>(Arrays.asList(13,17));
        SortedSet<SortedSet<Integer>> s = new TreeSet<SortedSet<Integer>>(
                Comparator.comparingInt(SortedSet::first));
        s.addAll(Arrays.asList(s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7));
        System.out.println(s);
```

This will be:

```
[[13, 14, 15, 16, 17]]
```

Is this something you’re expecting?

http://tpcg.io/HQONOhVV

If you want to go with TreeSet you need more strict comparator, like:
(compares by size descending, then same-sizes are compared by items one by one)

```
new TreeSet<>(((Comparator<Set<Integer>>) (o1, o2) -> o2.size() - o1.size()).thenComparing((o1, o2) -> {
                Iterator<Integer> i1 = o1.iterator();
                Iterator<Integer> i2 = o2.iterator();
                while (i1.hasNext() && i2.hasNext()) {
                    Integer n1 = i1.next();
                    Integer n2 = i2.next();
                    if (!n1.equals(n2)) {
                        return n1 - n2;
                    }
                }
                return 0;
            }));
```

You probably might want change the order of comparing (by size after by items.

http://tpcg.io/1FjcQ2XA

Comment: The accepted answer is accurate when the sets are disjoint, which seems to be the OP's use case.

Comment: Well, you might be correct, but still I’d recommend OP to write a bunch of unit test to check if accepted answer covers his needs. It could require some tuning.

Comment: Kaya3 is right, in my case sets are disjoint. Thanks to Makhno to point out it. +1.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working with the assumption that you're putting "values" in the set in sorted order, HashSet itself doesn't preserve the order of the insertion, but you could use [LinkedHashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html), from the doc:

> This implementation differs from HashSet in that it maintains a doubly-linked list running through all of its entries. This linked list defines the iteration ordering, which is the order in which elements were inserted into the set (insertion-order)."

You could use this behavior during printing.